# Activerecord request where has_many relationship is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to do a database query where it only returns results where a has_many relationship isn't empty. Below is an example where the has_many :gift_images :

```
Gift.joins(:gift_images).includes(:gift_images, :comments, :category, :user).select("gifts.*, COUNT(gift_images.id) AS gcount").where("gcount > 0")
```

Something like that, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use aliases on where statements, try the following

```
Gift.where("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gift_images WHERE gift_images.gift_id = gifts.id) > 0")
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer keeping db queries less "SQL-ish" when possible.

```
Gift.where(id: GiftImage.where('gift_id IS NOT NULL').select('gift_id') ).count
```